# How to convert XML to JSON in Java excluding some tags?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, org.json

I want to convert XML to JSON in Java but most of the answers focus on converting all tags in XML to JSON. But my requirement is to skip some of the tags and convert remaining tags to JSON. Any help would be appreciable.

I have tried `XML.toJSONObject(String);` method from the `org.json` package but it does not suggest any way to skip some tags.

Comment: the question is too unclear to give a useful answer - so: load your xml via jaxb into your domain objects and then e.g. via gson to json

Comment: If that method does not provide anything like that, you can easily implement it yourself: either load the whole XML into memory and remove unnecessary elements and attributes using DOM, or write a filtering reader using SAX and just make output directly to a JSON writer.

Comment: But that will consume lot of memory and time since my xml has almost more than 50k tags. Is there any other method to do this.

Comment: Could you resolve this? am also having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using gson simply using remove api in JsonObject under com.google.gson

lets suppose we  have test attribute in your model that you do not want to display,

```
      JsonObject jsonObj;
      jsonObj.remove("test");
```

You will be having the json object without test attribute.

Comment: Your way suggests to remove keys from JSON after converting complete xml to json But I don't want to convert complete xml to json (In the process of converting I want to skip some tags)